# Finding density using bulk stress equation

Tags: density

Basically, I'm using the equation $\frac{F}{A} = -B\times \frac{\bigtriangleup V}{V_o} $. Originally I had to find the change in volume given an initial volume (B and pressure ($\frac{F}{A}$) were given to me.

Now it's giving me the final density and is asking for the initial density. How do I approach this?

Comment: Can you explain your question clearly?

Comment: I wanted to avoid being specific about the question, but I might as well just give it. The deepest point in any ocean is in the Mariana Trench, which is about 11 km deep, in the Pacific. The pressure at this depth is huge, about 1.13  10^8 N/m2. (Take the bulk modulus of seawater to be 2.34  10^9 N/m2)/ The density of seawater at the surface is 1.03  10^3 kg/m3. Find its density at the bottom.

Comment: I suggest multiplying the term $\Delta V/V_0$ by $m/m$.  This will let you use density and delta-density in your original formula.  When you do this, with a bit of algebra, you will be able to derive an equation that allows you to solve for initial density in terms of the known variables.

Answer (score 1):

$$K=-\frac{dP}{\left(\frac{dV}{V}\right)}$$
$K$ is the bulk module, $P$ is the pressure, and $V$ is the volume.
If $K$ is constant, then we have:$$\frac{dV}{V}=-\frac{dP}{K}$$$$\Rightarrow\;\ln\frac{V_2}{V_1}=\frac{P_1-P_2}{K}$$$$\frac{V_2}{V_1}=\frac{\rho_1}{\rho_2}$$
$\rho$ is the density.$$\Rightarrow\;\ln\frac{\rho_1}{\rho_2}=\frac{P_1-P_2}{K}$$$$\Rightarrow\;\rho_2=\frac{\rho_1}{e^\left(\frac{P_1-P_2}{K}\right)}=\frac{1003}{e^\left(\frac{-1.13\times10^8}{2.34\times10^9}\right)}=1052.62\;kg/m^3$$